# Linking to a section of a Blazor WASM page

Tags: html, blazor, blazor-webassembly

How can I link to a section of a Blazor WASM page?

Documentation.razor code:

```
@page "/documentation"
....
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Groups</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        @foreach (var group in groups.Where(g => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(g)))
        {
            <tr><td><a href="#@gIndex">@group</a></td></tr>
            gIndex++;
        }

        <tr><td><a href="#@gIndex">Others...</a></td></tr>
    </table>
```

The above code creates a list of groups with hyperlinks like so:

```
/#0
/#1
/#2
/#3
```

However, when I click on the links, they route me to the root of the web app and not a section of the current page e.g.

```
/documentation#0
/documentation#1
/documentation#2
/documentation#3
```

If I go to /documentation in browser and append the sections manually, then the browser does the appropriate redirect.

I've attempted to hardcode the route like so `a href="documentation#@gIndex"` but that doesn't do anything.

Any ideas how I can get hyperlinking to a section on the same page to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This bug was raised a long time ago, follow here : [Hash routing to named element](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/8393)

try changing links as follows:

```
<a href="documentation#@gIndex" target="_top">@group</a>
```